# What exactly sys.XMLtype object type provided by Oracle 11g does

Tags: xml, oracle11g, xmltype

I have been searching for a description for the sys.XMLtype object type for Oracle 11g and I'm not really grasping it concept and I can only find XMLtype (i'm not quite sure if its the same thing). Can someone help explain how it works and what it does for me please?

Answer (score 0):

It is the Oracle data type for manipulating XML data within the database.  You can read the [XML DB Developer's Guide Document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/toc.htm) to understand how to process XML in oracle.